# Retrieve data with DDE in R using tcltk2 library

Tags: r, excel, tcl, dde, tcltk2

Connecting Excel with 'ABC' throught Excel works, connecting R with Excel by DDE works also, but how to connect R with 'ABC' application ?

I have application providing DDE interface, from Excel I could retrieve value from it with this DDE reference :

```
='ABC'|DDE!_nazwa_value
```

from R I've tried to use `tcltk2` library, as follows :

```
tcltk2::tk2dde.request(service="ABC", topic="DDE", item="_nazwa_value")
```

but error occurs :

```
Error in structure(.External(.C_dotTcl, ...), class = "tclObj") : 
  [tcl] remote server cannot handle this command.

[1] "Error in structure(.External(.C_dotTcl, ...), class = \"tclObj\") : \n  [tcl] remote server cannot handle this command.\n\n"
attr(,"class")
[1] "try-error"
attr(,"condition")
<simpleError in structure(.External(.C_dotTcl, ...), class = "tclObj"): [tcl] remote server cannot handle this command.
```

I'm only trying to use tcltk `dde` functions to retrieve data from application, I think that `item` part of my `tk2dde.request` is wrong, but I've tried various modification (without `_` for example), do you know any clues or resources for solving this problem ?

EDIT

something is wrong I don't see ABC server nor DDE topic on server-topic list : 
`tk2dde.services()` but Excel can still connect and retrieve value using `='ABC'|DDE!_nazwa_value`, DDE Query also do not see it

Comment: Would making `item` be `_nazwa_value` (without `{…}`) work? I'm totally on the wrong platform to check…

Comment: @Donal Fellows good try, but error is the same as above, mayby I should consider issues like registering DDE server, but Excel client works perfectly well so registering server seems to be not the issue and I could also make workaround and get data to Excel from 1ABS1 application and next from Excel to R with request tcltk2::tk2dde.request("Excel", "Data", "R1C1:R25C25") and it works perfectly well

Comment: Why the curly braces around "_nazwa_value"?

Comment: Who have marked my question as favorite ?

Comment: I don't think StackOverflow allows users to know who marks questions as favourite, but maybe that person wants to find the solution to your problem too.

Comment: Have you tried using the Tcl `dde` package directly, `package req dde; dde request ...`?

Comment: @mrcalvin there is no `dde` package at CRAN

Comment: I am referring to the Tcl package `dde`, that should come with windows builds of Tcl (and so with the Tcl bundle coming with R). What gives (untested):`.Tcl("package req dde")`?

Comment: @mrcalvin it gives '<Tcl> 1.4.0'

Comment: So, assemble and send your request in Tcl, for a try: `.Tcl("package req dde; dde request ABS DDE _nazwa_value")`

Comment: Is your server name `DDE`? From the documentation it looks like `topic` should be the server name.

Comment: Try the cmd line utility ddecmd.  `shell("ddecmd request -s ABC -t DDE -i _nazwa_value", intern = TRUE)` .   http://www.chrisoldwood.com/win32/ddecmd/ddecmd.html

Comment: One other thing to try would be to try tcltk2 from both 64 bit R and 32 bit R versions.

Comment: @Mako212 by Ive used 'DDE' as server name : `topic="DDE"` is it proper - I don't know, how to list server names ? DDESpy don't show everything

Answer (score 2):

You can read in the article about [DDE](https://wiki.tcl.tk/996) in tcl/tk wiki:

> *(Talking about using Internet Explorer)* ... All of the above experiments should "work" reliably, in that, from the user perspective, IE indeed acts as described. However, back in the Tcl process, [dde] typically throws a "remote server cannot handle this command" exception. That's because, in KBK's analysis, DDE gives no "way to distinguish 'result expected, but the server failed to provide it' from 'no result is expected'." The only way not to receive a DMLERR_NOTPROCESSED is to invoke "dde exec -async ..."

Note: i tried tcl examples of DDE using Excel + "request" and i got the same error as you: ***"remote server cannot handle this command"***.

Saludos!,

Comment: but connecting with those application with Excel through DDE works, connection from R to Excel by DDe works also, I simply don't know how to connect R directly with 'ABC' application

Comment: You could connect from R to Excel with tcltk2?. If yes, what "parameters" you've used?

Comment: tk2dde.request("Excel", "Sheet1", "R1C1:R101C25") - simple request which doesn't contain name of file

Comment: request : tk2dde.request("Excel", "{[filename.xlsm]Data}", "R1C1:R1C1") also works